# IOS: Pass data to VC programmatically

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, properties

I am trying to pass some data from one view controller to another. What makes things difficult is that the first VC is a hamburger menu (or tableview controller) and the second VC is inside of a tab bar controller.  I cannot use a storyboard segue with prepareforsegue as this does not work with tabs.  The only way to get the tabs to work, apparently, is to use the delegate method upon pressing a cell of the table view.

So far, I have tried two methods and while they both succeed in presenting the second view controller, neither method is passing the data.  Would appreciate any suggestions.

//Method 1 does not work.  Tries to reference destVC using its place in hierarchy

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    mainTabVC *tabBarController = (mainTabVC *)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
    UINavigationController *navController = tabBarController.viewControllers[0];
    myVC * destVC = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
      destVC.data = @"Data Point";
    [self.revealViewController pushFrontViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
}
```

//Method 2 does not work. Tries to identify destVC using its identifier in storyboard

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    mainTabVC *tabBarController = (mainTabVC *)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
    UINavigationController *navController = tabBarController.viewControllers[0];
      [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = self.storyboard;
    myVC *destVC =
    [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myVC"];
        destVC.data = @"data point";
    [self.revealViewController pushFrontViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
}
```

//in myVC there is a property named data as follows:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *data;
```

Comment: The first method seems correct, but what error are you getting? or why does it fail?

Comment: When i log out the value of self.data in the desVC, it shows (null)

Comment: why don't you use `Notification`?

Comment: Are you sure that `destVC` is not nil? Where and when do you log `data` and expect it to be non-nil?

Comment: I agree with Adeel, I'd use a notification, it's cleaner and more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyVC *destVC = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

//Print this and get the address.
NSLog(@"destVC is: %@ at: %p", destVC, destVC);
```

Then put the same print statement in the viewWillAppear function of the myVC class.  You can compare them to see if they are indeed the same.